# Best Practice for storing temp data across States in Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

I have a simple counter application made by Flutter using Bloc. The idea is after the user presses the increase button, it will delay for 2 seconds, show loading, then increase/decrease the value.

The counter bloc contains 2 states, `CounterValue` and `CounterLoading`. However, whenever I increase, the bloc starts creating a new CounterLoading object with a value of 0. To deal with this, I have to pass the current value at the `CounterValue` state to `CounterLoading` state, and after 2 seconds, **I have to pass again the current value of Loading state to CounterValue state to increase the value**. Hence this seems to be pretty redundant and confused when it comes to real situations where we have multiple states in the middle which don't need data while the first and last state emitted are dependent.

**What is the best practice to store temp data across states using bloc?**

**counter_state.dart**

```
class CounterState {
    int value = 0;
}

class CounterLoading extends CounterState {}

class CounterValue extends CounterState {}
```

**counter_bloc.dart**

```
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
    CounterBloc() : super(CounterValue()) {
      on<IncrementCounter>(
          (event, emit) async {
              emit(CounterLoading()..value = state.value);

              await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

              emit(CounterValue()..value = state.value + 1);
      },
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend investigating immutable states, which is very convenient while using BLoC. It means that instead of directly changing property values in the state, you are rather creating a new state object and replacing the previous state.

For this specific problem, I would recommend you to have a more complex state instead of having two separate states for Loading/Value. For instance:

State:

```
class CounterState {
  const CounterState({
    this.value = 0,
    this.isLoading = false
  });

  final int value;
  final bool isLoading;
}
```

BLoC:

```
class CounterBloc extends Bloc<CounterEvent, CounterState> {
    CounterBloc() : super(CounterValue()) {
      on<IncrementCounter>(
          (event, emit) async {
              final cur = state.value;

              emit(CounterState(value: cur, isLoading: true));

              await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));

              emit(CounterState(value: cur + 1, isLoading: false));
      },
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and it is really works for this problem. However, Is this solution practicable in realistic projects because we have 2 different ways to manage states in the application, once is define immutable states like recommended and the other one is mutable state?

Comment: While using BLoC, you should prefer using immutable states. This way, only the actual change in the state would trigger state update in BLoC, correspondingly re-render in the UI. I would recommend checking flutter_bloc documentation for more context.

Answer (score 2):

When state is more complicated than just 2 values, you should combine the use of [`Equatable` package](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) and `copyWith` method in your state.

1. `Equatable` makes it easy to tell that `stateA != StateB`. It's a replacement for manually overriding the `==` operator in your state class.
2. `copyWith` just returns a new state with zero or more of its values changed. It should be used basically every time you want to `emit` a new state.

State:

```dart
class CounterState extends Equatable {
  const CounterState({
    this.value = 0,
    this.isLoading = false
  });

  final int value;
  final bool isLoading;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [value, isLoading];

  CounterState copyWith({
    int? value,
    bool? isLoading,
  }) {
    return CounterState(
      value: value ?? this.value,
      isLoading: isLoading ?? this.isLoading,
    );
  }
}
```

Cubit:

```dart
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
  CounterCubit() : super(const CounterState());

  Future<void> increment() async {
    emit(state.copyWith(isLoading: true));
    await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    emit(state.copyWith(value: state.value + 1, isLoading: false));
  }
}
```

And for even larger apps where you might use custom objects, not just integers, strings and booleans, I recommend you take a look at [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) for creating models to include in your state with their own copyWith methods, etc. automatically generated.

Emits would look something like this for an `AuthState` with a `User` model:

```dart
void updateUserName(String newName) {
  emit(state.copyWith(user: state.user.copyWith(name: newName)));
}
```